# (Bootstrap) Square thumbnail size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I have some problem with thumbnail grid ( I use bootstrap).

Screenshoot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaqB5.jpg

My website: http://beta.otaku.vn

> Look thumnail. When my image is not square, thumnail list will be
>   broken. I try to make it square but no effect. View my website source
>   to more detail.

Comment: This is a statement, not a question. Tell us your problem and show us your code.

Comment: Maybe you provide a jsfiddle, codepen or whatever and check if it works there. Possibly there are some wrong closing elements etc.

Comment: Look thumnail. When my image is not square, thumnail list will be broken. I try to make it square but no effect.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your images are not the same size. The solution is

1. upload them with the same dimension or
2. use CSS.

Using css will solve your problem right away but the look of your images will be distort. You can try if you want to. Add these lines between your

```
.image img{
max-height:196px
max-width:196px;
}
```

Hope this help. (untested)